# Issue trying to add django-tables2 supprot to project

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am trying to follow the instructions for adding django-tables2 to a project:

http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html

I am following these steps.

1. pip install django-tables2
2. Add 'django_tables2' to INSTALLED_APPS
3. Add  'django.core.context_processors.request' to the context_preprocessors in your template setting OPTIONS.

when I restart and go to the app it complains that context.preprocessors is not an expected key. are the instructions wrong?  do they require a particular level of django and the django_tables2 extension?

note my OPTIONS section of settings PY to start looks like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

edited:

i did find the django.core package called out above contains the following contents:

```
import warnings

from django.template.context_processors import *  # NOQA
from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango110Warning

warnings.warn(
    "django.core.context_processors is deprecated in favor of "
    "django.template.context_processors.",
    RemovedInDjango110Warning, stacklevel=2)
```

so looks like the instructions for installing django-tables2 needs to be updated to mention this.

Comment: try django.core.context_processors.request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I used to have...  Notice the **django.core** bit.

```
#had to add this because of django_tables2:
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += ("django.core.context_processors.request",)
```

Comment: could you add a little more detail,  was that something you added as a line in the settings PY?  also could you comment on django and tables2 levels your using?

Comment: you have django. **template** .context_processors.request.  I have, and you even mention in your question, django. **core** .context_processors.request.  i.e. review your request line and what comes right after django.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I agree they are different.  The code in my question is from a freshly created django project.  The original project I was working with was from an older level and the level had been updated to 1.8.  I got the new project to see what the default values for the settings.py included.   that code was from that file.  I tried adding a context_preprocessors key entry to the options dict but django complained. the instructions for django_tables2 seem incorrect.

Comment: have you **tried** correcting the package name to django.core.context_processors.request?  do you still get the error?  don't over-complicate things.  i don't think either django or django-tables2 versions have much to do with your issue, as long as you are trying to pick up **context_processors.request** from the wrong package.

Comment: Was just following the instructions... and they listed it as PREprocessors in the instructions.   I think you are correct though on the package.  Just looked for the called out package and found code indicating the core based package is deprecated.

Comment: Still not sure if the original suggestion you made works for my version combinations.  I tried adding it to settings.py and got an error about the variable not being defined.

Comment: So what version of django are you using? 1.8 (mine) changed the config for template settings, but i might have 1.7 settings git-ed somewhere.

Comment: 1.8 django, will look and try again.  thanks for your assitance btw.

Comment: Sorry for not responding before,  I think so but I never added the line you suggested.  I left the structure as I had it.

Comment: Nah, no problem.  But from your errors, I think it had more to do with the structure of the template settings variable, as you said, than with the actual contents of the context processor package, as I stated.  i.e. I was right, but your code encountered a different error before, and, yes, it probably does have something to do with Django 1.8, because they restructured the template settings.